# Parse YAML with space name in JAVA

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

YAML is

```
innings:
  - 1st innings:
      team: Australia
      runs:500
  - 2nd innings:
      team: Australia
      runs:501
```

JAVA Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            Innings user = mapper.readValue(new File("a.txt"), Innings.class);
            System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(user,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Innings {
    public List<Inning> innings;    
}
class Inning{
    public int runs;
    public String team;
}
```

Error-trace:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "1st innings" (class Inning), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "runs", "team"])
     at [Source: a.txt; line: 3, column: 7] (through reference chain: Innings["innings"]->Inning["1st innings"])

Note: Please suggest other parser, if jackson isn't able to help here.

Comment: Just be aware that java devs feel great pain when they see you name classes with a lowercase letter first.

Comment: Or public non-final fields in non-private classes.

Comment: yes i understand, actually i had the same class with same name "Inning", to create this class temporarily i made one more class "inning"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it using custom-Deserializer. Thanks all.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class InningsParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Inning.class, new InningDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        try {
            Innings user = mapper.readValue(new File("a.txt"), Innings.class);
            System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(user,ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class Innings {
    public List<Inning> innings;
}
class Inning{
    public int runs;
    public String team;
}
class InningDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Inning> { 

    public InningDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public InningDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public Inning deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String nodeS = node.toString();
        nodeS = nodeS.substring(nodeS.indexOf(':')+1, nodeS.toString().lastIndexOf('}'));
        System.out.println(nodeS);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(nodeS,Inning.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with the `YAMLFactory` but if I modify your POJOs like this:

```
class innings {
  public inning[] innings;
}
class inning {
  @JsonProperty("1st innings")
  public inning_deep first;

  @JsonProperty("2nd innings")
  public inning_deep second;
}
class inning_deep{
  public int runs;
  public String team;
}
```

It seems to deserialize it ok, but obviously this is probably not enough for you. If this was JSON and I would replace the two `inning_deep` properties with an array and it would work just fine. I think this is a limitation in `YAMLFactory` and probably you will need to write a custom deserializer.

You might get more help by opening a issue [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues).
Please reconsider class naming to respect [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

*Note: normally I would not attempt to post an incomplete answer, but it doesn't look like anyone else know how to fix it.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
Yes i wanted an answer without hard-coding.
Can you suggest some other parser to solve this? Wouldn't matter even if it's in Python, Ruby, .NET as well. Preferably though in JAVA